# Handwritten signature visualization?

Tags: visualization, signature, handwriting

With the coming of devices like Samsung Notes, with a pressure sensitive pen (and with supposedly ink like experience), I was thinking it might be possible to use mobile devices as a signature pad. Can someone help me if there exist some open libraries (preferably java) / standard approaches for how to visualize data collected by a pen (xy coordinates, pressure, speed etc.) into an image?

What I mean is, that simply displaying the xy coordiantes won't look good enough. There should be at least some curve smoothing maybe other things to make it look as close to handwritten text as possible. And if there exist some standard ways for how to deal with that, I would like to avoid reinventing the wheel. Note that I am not concerned about OCR or any form of handwritten text recognition, just visualization.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any libraries, but I would guess that constructing a cubic spline would be sufficient. I would guess that any existing implementations will be more crude for speed - just straight lines between points.

Note that here you don't care about the nature of the shapes, so you could look for pen input smoothing; that got me to [Inkscape's smoothing](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-Creating.html), and you may be able to use its code for your own visualization.